# How to fix issue Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out while signing apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was able to sign my apk fine until I did some android studio update or reset something in jar files. Not sure why, but it keeps throwing the error:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out
```

when I try to sign my apk. I am running 100% native code and I keep seeing this come up in react native thread. Has anyone faced a similar issue before?

Comment: have you tried cleaning the build?

Comment: several times, but no luck

Comment: is this a way to ignore certain specific directories in intermediates?

Comment: clean, then rebuild just helped me. Not just clean or invalidate. Without rm -rf

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Cleaning .gradle in caches helped me. here's the commands :

```
rm -rf android/.gradle
rm -rf .gradle
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```

it will show you :
/.gradle/caches: Directory not empty ( as a link) , click on it and delete the .gradle directory and it will start working again.

Comment: This worked for me, however, be sure to backup the contents of any gradle.properties file that might live there.

Comment: saved me hours!

Comment: In my case it was enough to delete only the .gradle directory of the project.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply show hidden folder in Mac(cmd shift . (period)) and just delete the .gradle folder at the root of the project.